# Ä Umlaut-dots too close to the letter in Firefox

Tags: css, fonts, typography

In Mac-FF 41 (and 40) the Umlaut-dos of the letter Ä are rendered too close to the rest of the letter, as it shows in the picture below. In other Browsers however (Chrome, Safari) the type renders correctly.

[image]

The problem *only* occurs when I apply css "**text-transform: uppercase;**" to a small letter "ä". It looks fine when I use the actual uppercase letter "Ä".

The webfont I would like to use is "MuseoSans" – however the same problem occurs when I use a similar webfont "Equip-Light".

I did try playing with font-size and line-height – but the problem remains the same. Also with other Umlaut-letters "Ü" and "Ö" it seems to be ok, probably at least because the letters have a different 'architecture' of the letter.

Most of the answers I found at least close to the topic are related to UTF8-issues – but that's not the problem here. I hope that anybody here might have a suggestion what is causing this problem – and how I can solve it. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly its not the issue of browser, but of the font. the answer semms to me to be simple: creators of the fonts you use haven't created optimal Umlaut letters.

There are many fonts: some of them are good with Latin characters, and very bad with Cyrillic, or good with Cyrillic and bad with Scandinavian umlauts.

All fonts done by people - some of them aren't experienced enough or just invested few time in creation of such rare characters.

Take another font and be happy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What really leaves me puzzled is that the actual uppercase letter Ä seems to be perfectly ok – only when I apply "uppercase" through css to a small "ä" it looks 'muddy'. For now I'll probably just enter the headline in uppercase LETTERS instead up using css… although the 'dirtyness' of this approach does bother me a lot :/

Answer (score 0):

Just found the source for this problem: the ill-formated letters are coming from a PDF.

Solution: Rewriting the letters helps.

I had this problem already some time ago in a different context – seems to be mostly PDF-related…

Comment: How do you apply CSS text transforms to text inside a PDF?

Comment: ...generating a PDF from the rendered HTML/CSS?

Comment: I was actually just referring to copying text from a PDF.